# How do I shorten to write {{id}} instead of {{object.id}} in angularjs? (when 'object' is json)

Tags: angularjs

This maybe a too basic question, but I couldn't google it for ages.

Say I have $scope as

> $scope.object = {id:1, name:"stackoverflow"};

And in html, I want to call simply

> {{id}}

instead of

> {{object.id}}

Is there a simple way to achieve this? (without a loop to map json attributes to $scope variables etc)

Maybe something simple like... (I know this won't work)

```
<div ng-scope="object">
{{id}}
</div>
```

==== Update ===

Guess there's no default (natural or easy) way of achieving this without manipulating $scope. (i.e. adding more watches (= overheads) etc)

Well... after more research, I think this maybe a really bad idea in  angularjs. See this video.
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

I just wanted to use my existing code from Laravel (blade templating engine). Guess I will have to write '.'(dots) to prevent unexpected behaviors for now. I have like 100s of them, so it feels so repetitive.

This is just a simple task in backend frameworks.

I will vote up all the relevant your answers! :D

Thanks!

Comment: take a look to this question, is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300814/the-with-binding-of-knockoutjs-in-angularjs. the nwayve answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be a simple directive to do that:

```
MyModule.directive("ngShort", function(){
  return function(scope, elem, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngShort,function(){
      angular.extend(scope, scope.$eval(attrs.ngShort))
    }, true) 
  }
})
```

```
<div ng-short="object">
    {{id}}
</div>
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbccinFJZOdIK9vs1lqz?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, the variable "id" needs to be stored directly on the scope.  So, for example, in the controller you might do the following after loading the object:

```
$scope.id = $scope.object.id
```

As you mentioned, if you wanted to do this for all properties stored on in $scope.object, you would have to loop.  You could, of course, write a utility method to make this look okay in your code.

I find it hard to believe that this is worth while doing, even if there were some convenient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

{{object.id}} will be the simplest solution, if you want you can have

```
$scope.id = $scope.object.id ;
```

then you can use {{id}}